# Set div background color based on a percent (like progress bar)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

I have a div with some text and a percent value (for example it is 78%)
I want visualize percent as a background color of the div with origin text. It is must fill all the space of origin div not a line in the div

```
<div class="my-div">
    <div class="???" style="width: 78%"></div>
    My text
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
<div class="progressbar-wrapper">
    Some text
    <div class="progressbar" style="width: 78%"></div>
</div>

.progressbar-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.progressbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #dcf3dd;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>


 <div style="height:20px; ">
        My text
</div>
<div style="height:50px;width:500px;background-color:grey;">
    <div class="???" style="width: 78%;background-color: brown;height: inherit;">this is a progress bar</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "My text" must be over main div and progress bar. Now it is below.